# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003 - Already have a custom dialect

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I found a few solutions using java, but none of them seems to work after I convert the code to Kotlin. By the error code, I know that it is complaining about the fields with `@Type(type = "string-array")` at the Entity.

But is it possible to solve it using Kotlin?

How I can solve this error `No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003`?

> Solution that I tried: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/

**Repository**

```
interface SchemaRepository : CrudRepository<SchemaEntity, Long> {
    fun save(schema: SchemaEntity): SchemaEntity
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "schemas")
@TypeDefs(
    TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class),
    TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType::class)
)
class SchemaEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long? = null,

    @Type(type = "string")
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    val name: String,

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "schema", nullable = false)
    val schema: Schema,

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(name = "output_schema")
    val outputSchema: Schema?,

    @Type(type = "string-array")
    @Column(name = "tags")
    val tags: Array<String>?,

    @Type(type = "string")
    @Column(name = "owner")
    val owner: String?,

    @Type(type = "timestamp")
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    val createdAt: Timestamp? = Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()),

    @Type(type = "timestamp")
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    val updatedAt: Timestamp? = Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()),

)
```

**Custom dialect**

Located at `test` folder.

```
package com.dummy.repository.dialect

import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonNodeBinaryType
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
import java.sql.Types

class PostgreSQL10JsonDialect : PostgreSQL10Dialect() {
    init {
        this.registerHibernateType(Types.OTHER, JsonNodeBinaryType::class.java.name)
        this.registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, StringArrayType::class.java.name)
    }
}
```

**test/resources/application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.dummy.dataportalapi.repository.dialect.PostgreSQL10JsonDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

**Example of failing test**

```
import com.dummy.dto.Schema
import com.dummy.model.SchemaEntity
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
import org.springframework.data.repository.findByIdOrNull
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import java.sql.Timestamp

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@DataJpaTest
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class SchemaRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private val repository: SchemaRepository? = null

    val first = createDummySchemaEntity("First schema")
    val second = createDummySchemaEntity("Second schema")
    val third = createDummySchemaEntity("Third schema")

    @Nested
    inner class `save schema` {
        @Test
        fun `with success`() {
            val saved = repository?.save(first)
            val id = saved?.id ?: throw Exception("Not found ID on test data")

            val obtained = repository?.findByIdOrNull(id)
            validateEntityContent(first, obtained)
        }
}}
```

**Obtained error**

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
.
.
.
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003
```